# What is the reason that some functions in standard library just appear to be wrappers or aliases?

Tags: c

When I have looked into the source of glibc, I sometimes stumbles over functions that are wrappers that does nothing and only works as an alias. For example:

```
int
rand (void)
{
  return (int) __random ();
}
```

What is the reason for things like this? Why not just take the body of `__random()` and put it in `rand()`?

Comment: There are a variety of reasons. For example, some compilers contain a variety of system specific "builtin" implementations, so the source / header files simply tell the compiler to place their implementation in there. Another would by type casting from a more general function to a library conforming type. This is a very case specific question.

Comment: @Myst Sounds reasonable. How about a proper answer?

Comment: Myst is right that there are a variety of answers, and constructing a good answer for this is not easy. Stack Overflow is not a suitable forum for some deep/broad issues that arise in software engineering. Some library implementations may be shims to allow alternate plug-in implementations, helping separate the compiler from the library (e.g., so GCC can be used somewhere separately from the GNU C library). Some may be left as calls because they are deprecated/discouraged and not worth the effort of maintaining a copy of the code (which has costs and risks) just for them.

Comment: And there are more issues. Answers for any specific routine would require investigation, and answers for all cases in general requires explaining many problems, costs, thoughts, requirements, and other things that arise in building products, maintaining software, working between different organizations, and so on.

Comment: @klutt - sure :)

Comment: `Why not just take the body of __random() and put it in rand()?` In this specific case is so that the same code is not duplicated in two places.

Comment: @KamilCuk - The root functionality in [`random_r`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/random_r.c;hb=glibc-2.28#l353) is stateless while `rand()` requires a persistent state. Keeping two copies of the code is redundant, hence the specific use-case for `rand` keeps things DRY and reusable....

Comment: You mean glibc? There is a completely different library called glib.

Comment: @user253751 Yes. Corrected.

Answer (score 6):

This is a very case specific question as there are a variety of reasons for such a behavior. One answer cannot cover all the reasons for all the cases.

For example, some compilers contain a variety of system specific "builtin" implementations, so the source / header files simply tell the compiler to place their implementation in there.

Another reason would be to type cast from a more general function to a standard conforming type.

Some functions contain repeated functionality (think `printf` vs. `fprintf(stdin,...`), and using wrappers is a simple way to keep the code more DRY.

Specifically, [`__random`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/random.c;hb=glibc-2.28#l287) returns a `long int` and needs to be converted to `int` (which may or may not be the same, depending on your system).

In addition, `__random` reuses functionality in [`__random_r`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/random_r.c;hb=glibc-2.28#l353), but adds a lock to make the functionality thread safe.

Reusing the same functionality with minor variations (a global thread-safe state) keeps the code more DRY.